# Yii - Saving data back to Many-to-Many Relation database, from a dropdownlist with multiple-selection

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, many-to-many

(Please pardon my poor English.)
I am having 3 tables, say **Blog**, **User** and **user_blog**.

**Blog**

```
CREATE TABLE `Blog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**User**

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**user_blog**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_blog` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `blog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`blog_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and i have declared their relations in the respective AR models.

**Blog.php**

```
public function relations() {
   return array(
      'users' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'user_blog(blog_id, user_id)'),
   );
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function relations() {
   return array(
      'blogs' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Blog', 'user_blog(user_id, blog_id)'),
   );
}
```

And now, I have in my view the following codes:

```
<?php
   $data = CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), "id", "name");
   echo $form->dropDownList($blog,'users', $data, array('multiple'=>'multiple', 'size' => '5'));
?>
```

With the above code, a dropdownlist with multiple selection is successfully created, and the data from the database are successfully retrieved and the items that are supposed to be selected are successfully highlighted.

But here comes the problem. I have no idea how to implement the saving/updating function. No matter what options I have selected, the results are not saved back to the database.

Could anyone please help?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CRUD generator or do it yourself like this:

**Controller:**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
   $model = $this->loadModel($id, 'User');

   if(isset($_POST['User']))
   {
      $model->setAttributes($_POST['Message']);
      if($model->validate()) 
      {
         if($model->save()) {
            //do something here, eg. view updated record
         }
      }
   }

   $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

**view/update.php**

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('GxActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'user-form',
));
?>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'username', array('maxlength' => 32)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
        </div><!-- row -->
...
...
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'users'); ?>
<?php
   $data = CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), "id", "name");
   echo $form->dropDownList($blog,'users', $data, array('multiple'=>'multiple', 'size' => '5'));
?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'users'); ?>
...
...
<?php
echo GxHtml::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'));
?>
```

P.s read this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.overview

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. I have generated the forms using the CRUD. But the problem is the results are supposed to be stored into the `user_blog` table, which does not have any Model or CRUD operations generated. I suppose it requires extra coding to implement it?

Comment: You must have user_blog model. Without it, you won't be able to use ActiveRecord and you would have inserting it into database manually by sql queries.